# Background turning to white when i use autofill chrome

Tags: html, css, sass

I've designed a form field as shown in the image

[image]

but when I used the autofill circled in the blue box, the background and text color changes like in this picture

[image]

My SCSS code

```
.email__wrapper{

@include respond-to('small') {
    padding: 30px 10px;
}
.pork__container{
    padding: 146px 100px;
    background-color: color(darkerGreen);
    border-radius: 54px;
    background-image: url(./img/Fruit__CTA.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    @include respond-to('medium') {
        background-image: url(./Assets/Images/Submit_BG_Mob.png);
    }

    @include respond-to('medium') {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    @include respond-to('small') {
        padding: 60px 22px;
    }
}


&__heading__wrapper {
    width: 100%
}

&__form__wrapper{
    width: 100%
}

&__heading{
    color: color(lightWhite);
    max-width: 296px;
    @include respond-to('medium') {
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
    }
}

&__paragraph{
    color: color(lightWhite);
    @include respond-to('medium') {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 47px;
    }
}

&__field {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: color(lightWhite);
    border: none;
    

    
    &::placeholder{
        color: color(lightWhite);
    }

    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    
    &__wrapper{
        display:flex;
        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    }
}


&__submit{
    background-color: transparent;
    border:none;
    background-image: url(./img/submit_BG.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding: 9px;
    transform: scale(0.5);

}
.mc4wp-response, .mc4wp-response a{
    color: color(lightWhite);
}
.mc4wp-form-fields{
    margin-top: 30px;
    @include respond-to('medium') {
        margin-top: 47px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
}

.mc4wp-alert {
    margin-top: 20px;
    @include respond-to('medium') {
        text-align: center;
    }
}

}
```

how can I fix this? I've tried adding background as transparent and other stuff too. but nothing worked. Thanks in advance

Site URL: https://por-k-no.com/learn-more/

Comment: Define background color as transparent and if not resolved , kindly share link or code

Comment: Didn't work

here is the link:  [link](https://por-k-no.com/learn-more/)

Comment: you need to add ``box-shadow`` Check my answer below hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background not working on autofill try below CSS trick

```
.email__wrapper__field {
    box-shadow: 0 60px 0px inset #29711e;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: It worked, but the font color is black. how can i change it

Comment: you can change using ``-webkit-text-fill-color: #fff !important;`` CSS **answer updated**

Answer (score 0):

From the link I see you have given background color as green

```
.email__wrapper__field {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #29711E;
    color: #F2F2F2;
    border: none;
}
```

Change it to

```
.email__wrapper__field {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #F2F2F2;
    border: none;
}
```

Hope it may help.

Comment: This is not working. i tried this already

Comment: it is working , as i can see in your site. 
As you have given following css also which may be picked by some browser so giving priority is must

'
 `button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    max-width: 100%;
}`,

For defining priority give !important tag
 `.email__wrapper__field {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: #F2F2F2;
    border: none;
}`

Hope it may help